# Celery and multithreaded tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

I'm looking at Celery to perform a defined set of tasks spread over multiple machines.  Each machine can process any one of several tasks, but some of the tasks will require more machine resources than others.  Is there a way to manage these resources using Celery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Celery doesn't provide a means of measuring current/past resource utilization of workers and adjusting the amount of work they perform based on those measurements. However, you do have a few knobs to turn with Celery that can result in more predictable and more evenly distributed resource utilization (YMMV).

If you have tasks that have no performance requirement, you might consider limiting the number of tasks that can be performed over a given period of time with [rate limiting](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#rate-limits).

Another option is to use [celery queues](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#defining-queues) to your advantage. Depending on your needs, you might create a queue for light tasks and one for heavy tasks and then have workers with more horsepower listen to the heavy queue and those with less listen to the light queue (or more workers listening on heavy, less on light).